# How to keep IntelliJ IDEA from rearranging javadoc tags?

Tags: intellij-idea, javadoc, intellij-14

```
/**
 * Comment.
 *
 * <p>Hello
 *
 * @author me (me@domain.com)
 * @version $Id$
 * @since 0.1
 * @checkstyle ClassDataAbstractionCoupling (500 lines)
 * @checkstyle ClassFanOutComplexity (500 lines)
 */
```

When I reformat my code with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, the `@since` is placed after the `@checkstyle` tags. Is there any way to disable javadoc tag rearrangement on code reformatting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can uncheck *Enable JavaDoc formatting* in *Settings/Code Style/Java/JavaDoc*, which should fix the problem.

[image: IntelliJ IDEA settings]

However this means that no other formatting will be performed (wrapping, alignining, etc). I haven't found a way to disable just the rearranging of tags.

Comment: Thanks, quite sad that's the case though :(

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [this plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7157-javadoc) with disabled JavaDoc formatting in IDEA.

With that combination you still have an asterisk `*` inserted at newline, and you can configure all generated JavaDoc templates for each part of code.

It also has a feature of *upgrade* existing JavaDoc.